# Throwing an exception, why does it have to be static?

Tags: java, exception, static, throw

I've just started learning Java and I wanted to make an exception, but I don't understand why I should name it `static class` instead of just `class` - otherwise it will not compile. Could anyone explain it please?

```
public class Test
{

  class NrTooSmall extends Exception
  {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NrTooSmall
  {
    int n = 0;

    try
    {
      n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
      if (n < 0)
        throw new NrTooSmall();
    ....
```

Comment: Read about inner classes.

Comment: For example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Thank you :) WIll read up on it.

Comment: If you just started learning Java, don't use nested classes yet. Stick to the basic principle: each class Foo is defined in its own file Foo.java. Nested classes  will come later. Defining an exception as a nested class is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Two issue exist in the code :

First Add either `catch` or `finally` block try need at least any one.

Second You can't call the inner class like this.You need to use object of `outerclass` to call `inner class` like below :

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

i.e throw the exception like below

```
throw new Test.new NrTooSmall();
```